# How to hook obj-c selector from string(by tweak)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hook, theos, tweak

We can get ios installed bundle id list like this:

```
Class lsawsc = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
NSObject* workspace = [lsawsc performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace")];
NSArray *arr = [workspace performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"allInstalledApplications")];
for (NSString * tmp in arr)
{       
   NSLog(@"%@", tmp);
}
```

The arr(NSArray) is bundle id list. And I want to hide some bundle id by hook, in tweak. But I don't know how to write code for hook selector...Please help, thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve? What kinds of methods do you want to invoke on workspace, which return types do you expect and how do you want to modify the result?

Comment: OK, I rewrite the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just fill a new array with the filtered apps and use that:

```
NSArray *installedApps = /* result of allInstalledApplications invocation */;

NSMutableArray *filteredApps = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSString *app in installedApps) {
    if (/* filter/hook allows app */) {
        [filteredApps addObject:app];
    }
}

// Use filteredApps
```

*Note: LSApplicationWorkspace is a private API, so using it will prevent publication in the Apple App Store.*

Comment: Thank you very much